# Perl's conditional operator in string context

Tags: perl

Let's take the following minimalistic script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#
# conditional_operator.pl
#

use strict;

print ( 1 ? "true" : "false" )." statement\n";

exit;
```

I expect the output always to be "true statement". But when I execute this snippet, I see ...

```
deviolog@home:~/test$ perl conditional_operator.pl
true
```

The `" statement\n"` concatenation seems to be ignored.

My perl version is v5.14.2. I read the [perlop manual about the conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) and think, a string concatenation should be possible.

Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always include [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of every script.

To get your desired behavior, just add parenthesis so `print` is called with the entire argument instead of just the first part:

```
print(( 1 ? "true" : "false" )." statement\n");
```

If you'd had `warnings` turned on, you would've gotten this alert:

```
Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context
```

You can also avoid the undesired behavior by leading with a blank concatenation, or you could put a plus sign before the parenthesis:

```
print +( 1 ? "true" : "false" )." statement\n";
print ''.( 1 ? "true" : "false" )." statement\n";
```

Comment: An alternative would be: `print +( 1 ? "true" : "false" )." statement\n";`

Answer (score 2):

Adding `use warnings` to your code gives this:

> print (...) interpreted as function at ./cond line 10.
>
> Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at ./cond line 10.

Even better, add `use diagnostics` and you get this:

> print (...) interpreted as function at ./cond line 11 (#1)
>
> > (W syntax) You've run afoul of the rule that says that any list operator
> >     followed by parentheses turns into a function, with all the list
> >     operators arguments found inside the parentheses.  See
> >     "Terms and List Operators (Leftward)" in perlop.
>
> Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at ./cond line 11 (#2)
>
> > (W void) You did something without a side effect in a context that does
> >     nothing with the return value, such as a statement that doesn't return a
> >     value from a block, or the left side of a scalar comma operator.  Very
> >     often this points not to stupidity on your part, but a failure of Perl
> >     to parse your program the way you thought it would.  For example, you'd
> >     get this if you mixed up your C precedence with Python precedence and
> >     said
> >
> > `$one, $two = 1, 2;`
> >
> > when you meant to say
> >
> > ```
> > ($one, $two) = (1, 2);
> > ```
> >
> > Another common error is to use ordinary parentheses to construct a list
> >     reference when you should be using square or curly brackets, for
> >     example, if you say
> >
> > ```
> > $array = (1,2);
> > ```
> >
> > when you should have said
> >
> > ```
> > $array = [1,2];
> > ```
> >
> > The square brackets explicitly turn a list value into a scalar value,
> >     while parentheses do not.  So when a parenthesized list is evaluated in
> >     a scalar context, the comma is treated like C's comma operator, which
> >     throws away the left argument, which is not what you want.  See
> >     perlref for more on this.
> >
> > This warning will not be issued for numerical constants equal to 0 or 1
> >     since they are often used in statements like
> >
> > ```
> > 1 while sub_with_side_effects();
> > ```
> >
> > String constants that would normally evaluate to 0 or 1 are warned
> >     about.

Perl wants to explain the problems to you. You just need to ask it what you're doing wrong :-)